# DetailsView / UpdatePanel question

Tags: asp.net

I have a DetailsView grid inside of an UpdatePanel.  When the DetailsView is in Edit mode and the "Save" button is clicked, while the update is happening, I'd like the text of the "Save" button to change to "Saving...", and when the update is complete I'd like the text of the button to change to "Saved".

How is this done?  I can find the current text of the button with:

```
Button btnSave = (Button)DetailsView1.Rows[12].Cells[0].FindControl("Button1");
```

However, when I put the following in DetailsView1_ItemUpdating:

```
btnSave.Text = "Saving...";
```

And the following in DetailsView1_ItemUpdated:

```
btnSave.Text = "Saved";
```

The button text is not updating at all during the save and after the save is complete.  What am I doing wrong?  Does the UpdatePanel not automatically update as a result of the Text change?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do "Saving..." with client script and then set "Saved" from server side code because `DetailsView1_ItemUpdating` and `DetailsView1_ItemUpdated` usually occur on the same postback and you will never see `"Saving..."` caption.

Try

```
<asp:Button onClientClick="this.value='Saving...'" ... />
```

and do

```
btnSave.Text = "Saved";
```

in `DetailsView1_ItemUpdated` like you are doing right now.

Comment: Thanks.  The onClientClick for Saving... definitely worked, but the "Saved" still didn't - instead the button reverted to "Save"?

Comment: Do you have viewstate enabled? Check if it reaches the break-point, if you put one  `btnSave.Text = "Save";`

Comment: Yes already checked, it reaches the breakpoint, perhaps something in DetailsView is overriding the value after I set it?

Comment: Can you post the markup of detailsview (atleast pertaining to the button in quetion)?

Comment: <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <div class="progress" style="margin-left: 75px">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update"
                            Text="Save" OnClientClick="this.value='Saving...'" />
                    </div>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>